# Populate variable from a JSON Result in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I don't know if this is a basic stuff but I'm a having a hard time on populating a variable from a `JSON` result. I can't just find a right keyword on it.

What I want to do is populate this variable.

**Js File**

```
var opts = [
 { key: 1, label: 'High' },
 { key: 2, label: 'Normal' },
 { key: 3, label: 'Low' }
];
```

**Layer**

```
public IEnumerable<DropdownModel> ToLayerLevel()
    {
        List<DropdownModel> data = new List<DropdownModel>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn.MyConn()))
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, desc FROM PriorityLevel", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DropdownModel value = new DropdownModel();
                value.key = reader.GetInt32(0);
                value.label = reader.GetString(1);
                data.Add(value);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult ddlToLayerLevel()
    {
        DropdownLayers ddl = new DropdownLayers();
        var data = ddl.ToLayerLevel();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What relationship does that json array (which is a collection of items with properties `key` and `label`) have to do with your `DropdownModel` model which has properties `ID` and `Description`? (is `key` equal to `ID` and `label` equal to `Description`)

Comment: And you have shown a method named `LayerLevel()` which has no parameters, but your controller code calls a method named `ToLayerLevel()` which accepts one argument

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes. "`key` equal to `ID` and `label` equal to `Description`". My bad

Comment: Then edit you question to explain that (and fix the issue with your method name/parameter)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: do you want to change those field names to `key` and `label` or keep them as `id` and `description`?

Comment: are you using any js library like jquery?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yes. I'm currently using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an ajax call to the server action method where it will return the data you need

```
public JsonResult ddlToLayerLevel()
{
    var ddl = new DropdownLayers();
    var data = ddl.ToLayerLevel().ToList();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This will return an array of items with `key` and `label` properties, in JSON format

```
[{"key":1,"label":"High"},{"key":2,"label":"Normal"},{"key":3,"label":"Low"}]
```

Now you can call this action method using ajax . Here is a sample using jQuery `$.get` method.

```
var url="/YourControllerName/ddlToLayerLevel";
$.get(url).done(function(resultArray) {
                // resultArray is an array of items.
                //  Use it inside this callback method scope
             var opts=resultArray;
             console.log(opts);
          });
```

To avoid 404 Not found errors, when making ajax call's from external js files, you may use the `Url.Action` method to generate the correct relative path in your view file(*where you can execute C# methods like Url.Action*) and use that in your external js file.

For example, you can do like this in your razor view file

```
<script>
    var myProject= myProject|| {};
    myProject.layerLevelUrl ="@Url.Action("ddlToLayerLevel","YourControllerName")";
</script>
<script src="pathToYourExternalJsFile.js"></script>
```

Now in your external js file you can use it like

```
$.get(myProject.layerLevelUrl)
 .done(function(resultArray) {
     // resultArray is an array of items. Use it inside this callback method
     var opts=resultArray;
     console.log(JSON.stringify(opts));
 });
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your detailed explanation and helping me again.

Comment: I used to do something similar for the action urls but the `var myProject= myProject|| {};` is a nice trick. It would use any `myProject` variable present from a layout or partial view too.

Comment: That is just a sample. Ideally I would use a full namespace mycompany.myproject.mymodule.xxx. Also I always wrap code inside iEFE blocks and pass these to those blocks

Comment: @Shyju did you mean `IIFE` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) ?

Comment: @stom. Yes! Was typing from the phone app and did not pay much attention ;)

Answer (score 0):

Getting data using jQuery:

```
var opts = [];
$.getJSON("<your url here>", function(res){
    opts = res;
});
```

There is an alternate simplified way I use when I need to get objects created in c# directly into a js variable. It does come with pros and cons though

**pros**

1. Much quicker to code rather than having to create a controller and call a js ajax function every time.
2. Loads the entire page in one go and overall loads the data into js faster.

**cons**

1. The code doesn't go into your js file but instead into a cshtml file.
2. The information is only fetched in load time and the code can't be reused in real time when the page is still open.
3. If you don't need the js variable on page load, not using this would speed up the initial page load speed and will load the js information later.

First I create an extension function in static class as follows:

```
public static IHtmlContent ToJS(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, object obj)
{    
    return htmlHelper.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
}
```

Now in any cshtml file I can define the js variable by simply using the following:

```
@{
    DropdownLayers ddl = new DropdownLayers();
    var data = ddl.ToLayerLevel();
}

<script>
    var opts = @Html.ToJS(data);
</script>
```